# I'm trying to add a value to an int in one class and then use it in another, Java

Tags: java, class, int

So as the title says im struggling to add a value to an integer and then pass it to another class that uses it, then this class will pass it to the next and then that one will pass it over to the main class. Its an integer that changes the stat template of the enemies in my small game im writing.

I have tried to make constructors in two of my classes as I thought that was the problem, Ive tried to see if they work by passing some messages in them.
The problem seems to be that when I save something in the "private int l" It dosnt actually change the value of that int and I cant figure out why that is.

Here is my code, its probably not very pretty so if you have any suggestions to structure changes that I might wanna do please feel free too let me know!

Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stor {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner user_Input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Menu user = new Menu();
    EnemyValue monster = new EnemyValue();


    user.namn();
    user.AnvNamn = user_Input.next();

    user.introMeny();
    user.difficulty();
    System.out.println(“Your enemy has " + monster.HP + " HP and " + 
    monster.DMG + " Damage" );

    user_Input.close();
}

}

class Menu {
    Scanner user_Input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String AnvNamn;
    String difficultySvar;
    String nivåSvar;
    int svar;
    private int i; /
    private int l; 
    public int getL() {
    return l;
}
    boolean difficultyLoop = true;
    boolean felLoop = true;

    void introMeny() {
    System.out.println(“Welcome " + AnvNamn + "!");
}

    void namn() {
    System.out.print(“Pick a name: “);
}

    void difficulty() {
    do {
        System.out.println("\nWhat level do you want ?\n1 = Easy.\n2 = 
        Medium.\n3 = Hard.”);   
        svar = user_Input.nextInt();        
    if (svar == 1) {
        System.out.println(“Your not very brave are you ? Are you sure 
        this is how you wanna play ?”);
        difficultySvar = user_Input.next();
        if (difficultySvar.equalsIgnoreCase(“Yes”)) {
            difficultyLoop = false;
            l = 1;
        } // If ja 1
        else if (difficultySvar.equalsIgnoreCase(“Nej”)) {
            System.out.println(“Ahh good! I figuerd you would change 
            your mind.”);
        }
        else 
            System.out.println(“I don’t understand….”);
    } // if 1
    else if (svar == 2) {
        System.out.println(“Not to hard or to easy, a good choice! But 
        maybe you want to go for something harder ? Or maybe easier ?");
        difficultySvar = user_Input.next();
        if (difficultySvar.equalsIgnoreCase(“Yes”)) {
            difficultyLoop = false;
            l = 2;
        } // if ja 2
        else if (difficultySvar.equalsIgnoreCase(“No”)) {
            System.out.println(“I sure hope you don’t pick the easy 
                                 way…..”);
        }
        else 
            System.out.println("I don’t understand….");
    } // Else if 2
    else if (svar == 3) {
        System.out.println(“Damn! We have a big player here! Are you 
        sure you can handle this ?");
        difficultySvar = user_Input.next();
        if (difficultySvar.equalsIgnoreCase(“Yes”)) {
            difficultyLoop = false;
            l = 3;
        } // If ja 3
        else if (difficultySvar.equalsIgnoreCase(“No”)) {
            System.out.println(“Wuss.”);
        }
        else 
            System.out.println(“I don’t understand….”);
    } // Else if 3
    else {
        if (i == 0) {
        System.out.println(“Ha you thought you could fool the system?! 
                            The system fools you!”);
        System.out.println(“Nah but seriously, you can only choose 
                            between 1-3…..“);
        i++;
        } // if i 0
        else if (i == 1) {
            System.out.println(“Alright I get that its hard but 
                                COMEON!”);
            i++;
        } // if i 1
        else if (i == 2) {
            System.out.println(“OKEY YOU GET ONE LAST CHANCE!!”);
            i++;
        } // if i 2
        else if (i == 3) {
            System.out.println(“Alright thats it…. GET OUT!”);
            System.exit(0);
        } // if i 3

    } // Else
    } // do while loop
    while(difficultyLoop == true);

    } //Difficulty metod.
 } // Menu class.

class Nivå {
//Menu level = new Menu();
//int levelChoice = level.getL();
int levelChoice;
private int enemyLife;
public int getenemyLife() {
    return enemyLife;
}
private int enemyDMG;
public int getenemyDMG() {
    return enemyDMG;
}
Nivå(){
    Menu level = new Menu();
    levelChoice = level.getL();
    System.out.println("testNivå");
}
void fiendeLiv() {
    if (levelChoice == 1) 
        enemyLife = 100;
    else if (levelChoice == 2)
        enemyLife = 150;
    else if (levelChoice == 3)
        enemyLife = 200;
} // fiendeliv method

void fiendeDMG() {
    if (levelChoice == 1) 
        enemyDMG = 5;
    else if (levelChoice == 2)
        enemyDMG = 10;
    else if (levelChoice == 3)
        enemyDMG = 15;

} // fiendeDMG method
} // Nivå class

class EnemyValue {
public int HP;
public int DMG;
int maxLife; 
int maxDMG;

EnemyValue(){
    Nivå stats = new Nivå();
    maxLife = stats.getenemyLife();
    maxDMG = stats.getenemyDMG();
    System.out.println("TestEnemyValue");
}

void rank1() {
    HP = maxLife;
    DMG = maxDMG;
} // rank1 easy method

} // EnemyValue class
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that when you save something in l (poor choice of a variable name, by the way) it does not save the value. How do you know that? Where in the code do you check whether the value is saved?

In the constructor for class Nivå you create a new Menu and then call getL() on that menu before you have ever set the value of that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Everything runs at the start of your `public static void main(String[] args)` method, and nothing will run if its instructions are not in there. For example, you are not actually creating any Niva objects in the main method, so the Niva constructor is never called. That is one issue. The other is your constructors are creating new instances of objects and then getting their values; this gives you empty values from a brand new object:

```
Nivå(){
    Menu level = new Menu(); // Don't do this. This is an empty menu
    levelChoice = level.getL(); // Getting the blank L value from the empty menu
    System.out.println("testNivå");
}
```

Instead, you need to define constructors with parameters to pass the values into the class like this:

```
Nivå(int level){ // add an int parameter
    levelChoice = level; // Direct assignment
    fiendeDMG(); // Call this in the constructor to set up your last value
    System.out.println("testNivå");
}
```

Then, when you call the constructor (which you must if you want it to exist), include the parameter. Inside the Stor class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner user_Input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Menu user = new Menu();

    user.namn();
    user.AnvNamn = user_Input.next();

    user.introMeny();
    user.difficulty(); // Run this before creating the other classes; you need the l value

    Nivå niva = new Nivå(user.getL()); // Creates new Niva while also assigning l to the levelChoice and then getting DMG
    EnemyValue monster = new EnemyValue(/*add some parameters for life and dmg*/);

}
```

There is still more that needs to be done, like modifying the constructor of the EnemyLevel. Just remember that methods are never called unless they connect to something running from main and use parameters in functions and constructors to pass on data to other objects. Hope this helps.